# Display string on page xhtml

Tags: xhtml

I have this code:

```
if (comparingList.size()<3)
{

return "text1" + "text2" + "text3 ";

}
```

I want to display this text on page `*.xhtml` in this style:

```
text1 text2
text3
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple! You must change this `return "text1" + "text2" + "text3 ";`

to this `return "text1" + "text2<br/>" + "text3 ";`